# How to select text by paragraph in VS Code with a keybinding?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-binding

I've found how to customize a keybinding for jumping to the closest empty line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308649/how-to-navigate-by-paragraph-or-block-travel-in-vs-code).

But I wonder if I can, in the same way, set a keybinding for selection of paragraph or to the next empty line. I'd like it to select from where the cursor is to the next (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>) or previous empty line (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>)

More generally, I don't know how to search for existing, valid "command" to configure my own keybindings in the `keybindings.json` file.

Comment: Hi, do you want to select from where the cursor is to the next empty line or back to previous empty line, then select until next empty line? I assume the 2nd since you wrote "paragraph" but just making sure. Bindable commands are findable e.g. if you open keyboard shortcut settings in VSCode, you can also search them.

Comment: @Destroy666 No I mean the first one. I'd probably used the jump to next empty line shortcut I've set up to place my cursor on a empty line if I want to select from there

Comment: Now I'm very confused with your 2nd sentence above. Please edit the initial post with 2 screens - example of where the cursor is initially and what exactly needs to be selected after pressing the hotkey combination.

Comment: @Destroy666 I'd like it to select from where the cursor is to the next (with `Ctrl+Shift+DownArrow`) or previous empty line (with `Ctrl+Shift+UpArrow`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind `cursorMove` command with proper args. To bind:

- selecting from cursor to next blank line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>
- selecting from cursor to previous blank line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

you can use:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "to": "nextBlankLine",
            "select": true
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
        "command": "cursorMove",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "to": "prevBlankLine",
            "select": true
        }
    }
```

Add it to `keybindings.json` by e.g. executing Command Palette (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) -> **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)** command.

As a bonus, to bind one shortcut to select an entire paragraph, as the title of the question suggests, a [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) macro can be used:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+a",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "cursorMove",
                "args": {
                    "to": "prevBlankLine"
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "cursorMove",
                "args": {
                    "to": "nextBlankLine",
                    "select": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Check [cursorMove](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) documentation for more info.